# compile lua shared object into embeded c

Tags: c, lua, embedded

i have this code (`zstring.c`)

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include <string.h>

static int zst_strlen(lua_State *L)
{
    size_t len;
    len = strlen(lua_tostring(L, 1));
    lua_pushnumber(L, len);
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_zstring(lua_State *L) 
{
    lua_register(L,"zst_strlen", zst_strlen);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my `lua` embedded

```
int main (){
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

i do not want compile `zstring.c` to `zstring.so` object

i want `zstring.c` compile into my embedded `lua` then i can call `zstring` from `test.lua` and use it

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by including the zstring source file then calling `luaopen_zstring` after initializing Lua:

```
#include "zstring.c"

int main (){
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_zstring);
    lua_call(L, 0, 0);
    luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

It should be noted that even if you do not want to generate a shared library, you can still create an object file for `zstring` (by using the `-c` flag with `gcc`, for example). You can then link that object file with your main source.

The steps for doing this are roughly:

1. Compile `zstring.c` to an object file (e.g. `gcc -c -o zstring.o zstring.c`)
2. Create a header file named `zstring.h`:

   ```
   #ifndef ZSTRING_H
   #define ZSTRING_H
   int luaopen_zstring(lua_State *L);
   #endif
   ```
3. Include the header in your main source file:

   ```
   #include "zstring.h"

   int main (){
       L = luaL_newstate();
       luaL_openlibs(L);
       lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_zstring);
       lua_call(L, 0, 0);
       luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");
       lua_close(L);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
4. Compile the main file with the `zstring.o` object file linked (e.g. `gcc -o myprogram main.c zstring.o`)

Comment: Do not call `luaopen_*` functions directly, call them through lua. While it may work (and certainly will for this `luaopen_zstring` function) it is better practice to always call them the normal way. The canonical way to do this is to edit the linit.c file included in the lua sources to add the desired modules to the list that luaL_openlibs loads.